# POI4XPAGES word template format

Tags: xml, apache-poi, xpages

I'm using POI4XPAGES but I have a problem with Word template format.

It use the syntax '<< name>>' in word docx to pass field value. But if i try to do this with Word 2013 it doesn't work.

I renamed the docx in a zip file to see the xml structure in document.xml file and i've seen that the structure of a Word2013 file is different from the structure of the docx (made with Word 2006) you can find in the sample db

this is the xml you can find in the sample template (and it works)

```
<w:r>
   <w:tab/>
   <w:t><<name>></w:t>
</w:r>
```

this is the xml you can find when you modify and save again the sample docx with Word 2013 (and it doesnt work)

```
<w:r>
   <w:tab/>
   <w:t><<</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
<w:r>
   <w:t>name</w:t>
</w:r>
   <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
<w:r>
   <w:t>>></w:t>
</w:r>
```

Any suggestion to make it works with recent word versions?

Thanks

Comment: The `w:type="spellStart"` means there is an open spell check. This is also with Word 2007. 

So open the Word document. You will see the text "name" underlined with a red wave line. Rigth click that word and select `Ignore`. Now save.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have any direct experience with Word - but the markup suggests that there is some formatting for the field you add (just like formatting text).

So could you either mark the entire section for spell check (so that `<<name>>` occurs as a string in the markup) or perhaps disable spell checking (for the whole document - or just for the section with the tag)?

HTH
/John